# Paired one sided binomial hypothesis test with two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have paired sets of binomial data $(X_i, Y_i)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, N$. If I want to test if a the mean of $X_i$ is larger than the mean of $Y_i$, I do a binomial hypothesis test. What if I want to test if the set $\{ X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ has an average mean that is higher than $\{ Y_i\}_{i=1}^N$?

For example, i divide a class into siblings, with e.g. older sibling $X_i$ and younger sibling $Y_i$. The siblings play a game (not zero sum - they can both win and both lose), and I record the number of wins for each student. I can use a one sided binomial test to determine if each older sibling is significantly better than their younger sibling. How do I determine the significance with which older siblings on average are better than younger siblings?

Comment: Do you mean that if Y wins then X loses, and if Y loses then X wins? If so, you need to drop X or Y, because one of them has no any additional information.

Comment: The siblings play the same game, but its not zero-sum. They can both win or both lose.

Comment: Use McNemar's test.

Comment: It seems like McNemars test is two sided - and tests whether the paired samples were drawn from the same distribution. I want to do a one-sided test.

Comment: this paper appears to tackle the problem https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9a21/23fc21ac2b26c3ed95f2636a5c9c0bd8e842.pdf